# Visual Studio Debug date has changed due to windows date manually changed

Tags: date, debugging

I have added a system date checker in my first form inorder to check whether software has expired. in order to check this i updated windows date manually. Now visual studio debugger only reflects changes done to the program if i manually adjust to future date further to the last build. How to resolve this

Comment: Change detection is based on file timestamps. Backdating the time means the source code is older than the binary, so no rebuild is needed. Best solution is to test on a different system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.